# Xamarin binding displays nothing with no error

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to bind data like below, all data was fine and no error found.
But it displays nothing. (Xamarin-Visual Studio)

In the xaml,

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:SalesOrderDetailViewModel x:Name="vmSalesOrderDetail" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="mainLayout" >
            
            <ListView x:Name="lView"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"       
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SaleOrderDetail.Items}" 
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                    HeightRequest="{Binding Path=Height, Source={x:Reference mainLayout}}"
                    MinimumHeightRequest="{Binding Path=Height, Source={x:Reference mainLayout}}"  >

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       VerticalOptions="End"
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                       x:Name="lblDescription"   />

                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ItemID}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="End"  
                                       x:Name="lblItemID" 
                                       MinimumWidthRequest="50" />

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    
            </ListView>
    
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

and in the viewmodel,
[image]

and the object here,

[image]
[image]

Could you give me a bit of advice for me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do NOT post code as images!

Comment: your DataTemplate is a grid with nothing in it, so of course it doesn't display anything

Comment: I could not save the codes. It says 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details'. :<

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot the code when I copy and paste.

Comment: SaleOrderDetail does not call PropertyChanged, so if the data is loaded after the UI, it will not refresh the UI

Comment: @Brian Have you solved this ? You can have a try with coding to set `ItemSource` for `ListView` to check whether it works .

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the following ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

It simply contains a grid with a couple of column and row definitions. This won't show anything useful when you run the App. Are you sure you are not missing something here?